# show products in a specific category in html

Tags: html, css, django

i have a products and categories Model already implemented in models.py in a django application.

In an html template i want to show products of a single category that i want to define in html, like category == example or something similar.

```
class Product(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

this is the models.py snippet, below is the html snippet that i am trying to use

```
{% for product in category.products.all %}
```

I am already using this snippet to show products on category page, the category is going to be defined using the category url, but in this case i want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use filters in your views.py**

***views.py***

```
def yellow_products(request):
    y_p = Product.objects.filter(category="yellows")
    data = {'yellow_data':y_p}
    return render(request,'template.html', data)
```

***in HTML***

```
{% if yellow_data %}
    {% for product in yellow_data %}
       <p>product.id</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

---

**Another example**

***views.py***

```
def specific_products(request):
    y_p = Product.objects.filter(category="yellows")
    g_p = Product.objects.filter(category="green")
    data = {'yellow_data':y_p,'green_data':g_p}
    return render(request,'template.html', data)
```

***in HTML***

```
{% if yellow_data %}
    {% for product in yellow_data %}
       <p>product.id</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% if green_data%}
    {% for product in green_data%}
       <p>product.id</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Please check this tutorial for details
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/